# DocumentPickerDelegate not working after update to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickervc

I've tried to put a documentPicker to get a file from iCloud but Actually my app opens the documentMenu to import a file (iCloud, Dropbox) and when I choose iCloud, I present the document picker with my files. When I've to delegate the file to documentPicker(_ ...) [documentPicker.delegate=self.delegate]  function is never called because my class does not conform to protocol

```
import UIKit

class ImportKeyViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var openWithLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var transparentBackgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var iCloudButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var iTunesButton: UIButton!

    weak var delegate : UIDocumentPickerDelegate?

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL){
        print("Entre a documentPicker")
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
       print("Sali a documentPicker")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("llegue")
        setUpUI()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.transparentBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 220/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 0.7)
        })
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.transparentBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        })
    }

    @IBAction func closeButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController (documentTypes: ["public.text","public.content"], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate? = self.delegate!
        self.present(documentPicker, animated:true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I've the obligatory and optional methods for UIDocumentPickerDelegate but it's not working as you can see in  image below

This is my first iOS App, hope you can help me.

Comment: "as you can see in image below" Nothing there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question by copying and pasting the relevant code and a clear description of which parts works and which parts do not.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. Image Updated

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, I'll do that

Comment: Again, please copy and paste your actual code. Do not post code as images. It's too hard to read and difficult to reference when posting answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the new syntax of the `didPickDocumentAt:` delegate method, looks like it's changed a bit.

-- edit

Your `ImportKeyViewController` should inherit the `UIDocumentPickerDelegate`. A nice way to do this is by creating an extension, that way it's easily noticeable what methods are delegate methods, and what are your methods.

Like so:

```
extension ImportKeyViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL){
        print("Entre a documentPicker")
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
       print("Sali a documentPicker")
    }

}
```

Comment: This one? 
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL){...}

Comment: In the image you posted, but removed now, you could notice the compiler errors. About your viewcontroller not confirming to the delegate. You can check out the delegate methods by hitting command and clicking on the UIDocumentPickerDelegate.

Comment: Ah now i see what you're doing wrong, let me edit my answer.